# Node.js flow control

Tags: node.js

My question is the following:
I want to return the result returned by the callback.

```
exports.process_logs = function(file, process_func, process_parsedLog) {
var logs = [];
var log = null;
var counter = 0;
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(read_error, content) {
    if (read_error) return sys.error(read_error);

    // TODO:: Remove these hardcode rails filters
    // switch filters and split functions to a nested helper in process func
    content.split(/Processing /).forEach(function(msg, index) {
        if ((tmp = process_func(msg, index)))
            logs.push(tmp);
    });
    log = process_parsedLog(logs);
});
console.log(log);
return log;
```

};

But the variable "log" still null, although when I check it with console.log(log) just after "log = process_parsedLog(logs);" gives the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that fs.readFile is an asynchronous function and the process_logs function finishes its execution before readFile invokes the callback you passed to it. You should use promises for these situations: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

```
exports.process_logs = function(file, process_func, process_parsedLog) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var logs = [];
    var log = null;
    var counter = 0;
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(read_error, content) {
        if (read_error) deferred.reject(sys.error(read_error));

        // TODO:: Remove these hardcode rails filters
        // switch filters and split functions to a nested helper in process func
        content.split(/Processing /).forEach(function(msg, index) {
        if ((tmp = process_func(msg, index)))
            logs.push(tmp);
        });
        log = process_parsedLog(logs);
        deferred.resolve(log);
    });
    // the result is not available yet
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: You don't have to use promises. You could just stick to normal callbacks and use other techniques to avoid callback hell like naming your callback functions or using the async library

Comment: @AndyD yes, you are right. But it is easier when you use them (especially when you have sequences or having to wait for multiple async actions to finish).

Comment: the async module solves that problem nicely in my experience. Have a look here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918477/elegant-way-to-call-a-callback-function-after-other-callbacks-returned/13918510#13918510

Comment: @DanielUzunu I have used promises like u mentioned, but the return value is not what I expected instead I get the { promiseDispatch: [Function], valueOf: [Function] }

Comment: you get the data using process_logs(...).then(succesCallback, errorCallback);

Comment: @DanielUzunu thank you this was really a great help, and it solves my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the return in the callback function of the filesystem. But the function stays asynchronous. You cannot use the return value instantly:

```
log = process_parsedLog(logs);
return log;
});
```

You should keep the functions asynchronous, if you want to have a module like this, add a callback function to your anonymous function you want to export, like:

`exports.process_logs = function(file, process_func, process_parsedLog, callback)`

When the fs is done it will call the callback you passed in by `return callback(err, log)`

You can use promises as well here to avoid a pyramid of callback functions.